# macOS change SSID based on Location

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, network, wifi, settings

I have multiple SSIDs in the building.

1. When I choose a different Location, how do I make it connect to a different SSID?
2. When I choose a Location where Thunderbolt Ethernet is first in the service order, how do I make it disconnect from the SSID but leave Wi-Fi enabled for AirDrop?